# Are there four numbers in AP such that their prime factors are also in AP?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

The prime factors of $40807$ are $(13, 43, 73)$ are in arithmetic progression.

The prime factors of $55125 $ are $(3, 5, 7)$ are also in AP.

The prime factors of $69443$ are $(11, 59, 107)$ are also in AP.

Moreover, the three numbers $(40807, 55125, 69443)$ are also in AP. It is the smallest AP of three positive composite integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ and the prime factors of each of these numbers are also in some arithmetic progression. There are several other such triplets. But when it comes to four such numbers, there seems to be none. Is there any reason why a such a AP of four numbers cannot exist?

**Question 1**: Is there an AP of four composite coprime positive integers such that the prime factors of each of these four numbers are in some AP?

**Update**: No solutions below $2.5 \times 10^9$.

Comment: So the first trivial example is $5,11,17,23$ and if you so choose, $29$

Comment: Do you also want to exclude semiprimes then?

Comment: @Asinomás  4 primes in AP it fails to satisfy the condition that the prime factors of each of these numbers must also in in AP. For example, consider $5, 11, 17, 23$. The prime factors of $5$ are not in AP since $5$ has only one prime factor but to form an AP, we need at least three numbers.

Comment: @KeithBackman $4$ primes in AP cannot be a solution due to the reason explained above.

Comment: Oh ok, I was not aware arithmetic progressions must have at least $3$ terms I guess.

Comment: Two factors are always trivially in arithmetic progression. One factor is not allowed since OP asked for composite numbers, but I assume the prime factors of 25 are in arithmetic progression? Are the prime factors of 75 3, 5, and 5 or just 3, 5?

Comment: @gnasher729 The $75 = 3 . 5^2$, its prime factors are $(3,5)$ only. Are $(3,5)$ in AP? No, because to form an AP, we need at least three terms. E.g. $3,5,7$ are in AP. Similarly $1,3,5$ are in AP. But $3,5$ alone is not in AP. Next, what if you consider prime factors with multiplicity i.e. the prime factors of $75$ are $(3,5,5)$. Even in this case the three numbers $(3,5,5)$ are clearly not in AP. If you consider prime factors with multiplicity/repetition then obviously they will not be in AP since their difference will be zero where as other terms will have a non zero difference.

Comment: Nilotpal, change your question then: Add that each number must have at least three distinct prime factors, all in arithmetic progression. And no, it’s not a requirement that numbers in arithmetic progression are at least three. Any two numbers are in arithmetic arithmetic progression.

Comment: @gnasher729 Technically even one number alone is in AP. But such APs will lead us exactly in the direction of the lines of arguments such as $1$ is or is not a prime. I expect someone to know that any meaning math cannot done by a one number AP or a two number AP. So lets not nitpick over it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment. I think that you're looking for a solution without using a calculator or PC but maybe this gives some insight. I did a quick search where I look for in the range $0\le\text{n}\le10^6$.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
ParallelTable[
  If[Length[
      DeleteCases[
       Table[If[PrimeQ[Part[Divisors[n], k]], Part[Divisors[n], k], 
         a], {k, 1, Length[Divisors[n]]}], a]] >= 3 && 
    Length[DeleteDuplicates[
       Differences[
        DeleteCases[
         Table[If[PrimeQ[Part[Divisors[n], k]], Part[Divisors[n], k], 
           a], {k, 1, Length[Divisors[n]]}], a]]]] == 1, n, 
   Nothing], {n, 0, 10^6}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]={105, 231, 315, 525, 627, 693, 735, 897, 935, 945, 1575, 1581, 1617, 
1729, 1881, 2079, 2205, 2465, 2541, 2625, 2691, 2835, 2967, 3675, 
4123, 4301, 4675, 4715, 4725, 4743, 4851, 5145, 5487, 5643, 6237, 
6615, 6897, 7623, 7685, 7875, 7881, 8073, 8505, 8901, 9717, 10285, 
10707, 11025, 11319, 11339, 11661, 11913, 12103, 12325, 13125, 14175, 
14229, 14553, 14993, 15435, 15895, 16377, 16461, 16929, 17353, 17787, 
18375, 18711, 19845, 20213, 20631, 20691, 20915, 21505, 22477, 22869, 
23375, 23575, 23625, 23643, 23779, 24219, 25327, 25515, 25725, 26331, 
26703, 26765, 26877, 27951, 28861, 29151, 29341, 29607, 32021, 32121, 
32851, 33075, 33335, 33957, 34983, 35739, 36015, 38425, 39375, 40587, 
40807, 41905, 42525, 42687, 42911, 43659, 46305, 47311, 48635, 49011, 
49131, 49321, 49383, 50787, 51425, 53361, 54739, 55125, 55581, 55637, 
56133, 59535, 59563, 60297, 61625, 61893, 62073, 63017, 65625, 67731, 
68241, 68607, 69443, 70875, 70929, 71029, 71485, 72657, 73117, 75597, 
75867, 76545, 76751, 76985, 77175, 78337, 78993, 79233, 79475, 80109, 
80189, 80631, 83503, 83853, 84721, 86437, 87453, 88821, 91875, 95631, 
96363, 98923, 99225, 99485, 101065, 101177, 101303, 101871, 102131, 
102311, 104575, 104949, 107217, 107525, 108045, 108445, 111381, 
113135, 116875, 117875, 118125, 119377, 121471, 121761, 124509, 
124729, 127575, 127581, 127813, 128061, 128625, 130977, 131043, 
133825, 138915, 143479, 146481, 146969, 147033, 147393, 148149, 
151593, 152279, 152361, 157339, 160083, 160993, 163493, 164923, 
165375, 165831, 166453, 166675, 166743, 168335, 168399, 170097, 
174845, 176149, 177289, 178605, 180075, 180891, 184265, 185679, 
186219, 192125, 192763, 193315, 194937, 195657, 196875, 196883, 
202027, 203193, 204723, 205821, 207217, 208639, 209525, 210239, 
212201, 212625, 212787, 213931, 217167, 217971, 218285, 221757, 
222865, 226347, 226791, 227601, 228241, 229635, 229957, 231525, 
232667, 236555, 236979, 237699, 240327, 240463, 241893, 243175, 
251559, 252105, 257125, 258427, 260797, 262359, 263683, 265227, 
266463, 268203, 270215, 275625, 278185, 286893, 289089, 291597, 
292201, 294011, 294409, 296367, 297675, 298351, 305613, 307461, 
308125, 311023, 314847, 315935, 321651, 323317, 323637, 323733, 
324135, 328125, 328831, 329759, 334143, 334907, 337393, 343621, 
346317, 347687, 352231, 354375, 357425, 358343, 361691, 365283, 
365585, 373527, 375747, 381433, 382725, 382743, 383165, 384183, 
384569, 384925, 385875, 386389, 392931, 393129, 396341, 397375, 
397891, 398397, 407305, 412129, 412647, 415817, 416745, 416941, 
427063, 434797, 439443, 441099, 442179, 444447, 454779, 456909, 
457083, 459375, 460401, 467443, 470051, 472021, 474513, 477987, 
480249, 481213, 490141, 494615, 496125, 497087, 497203, 497425, 
497493, 499913, 500229, 505197, 505325, 506717, 509615, 510291, 
512029, 520421, 522875, 523979, 530491, 535815, 537065, 537625, 
540225, 542225, 542673, 547973, 548359, 554631, 557037, 558657, 
559551, 563473, 565675, 577527, 584375, 584521, 584811, 586177, 
586971, 589375, 590625, 593047, 598553, 600081, 609579, 614169, 
617463, 623645, 624169, 629821, 637875, 638361, 642061, 643125, 
645569, 651501, 653913, 654065, 654387, 663247, 665271, 669125, 
676133, 679041, 680373, 682803, 683243, 685115, 685279, 688905, 
694575, 704671, 710937, 711773, 712385, 713097, 719331, 720107, 
720981, 721927, 725679, 729973, 754677, 756315, 758951, 763873, 
767643, 782585, 785137, 787077, 790901, 795681, 797597, 799389, 
804287, 804609, 811927, 821197, 825373, 826875, 828733, 829961, 
831417, 833187, 833375, 834537, 839843, 841675, 850297, 860679, 
867267, 867981, 871563, 874225, 874791, 877951, 885167, 888681, 
889101, 893025, 894691, 899963, 900375, 916839, 921325, 922383, 
935857, 939401, 944541, 950669, 950779, 959239, 959435, 960625, 
964953, 966575, 970911, 971199, 972405, 983005, 984375}
```

So, I will pick one value to show that is true. When $\text{n}=959435$ we have the following distinct prime factors: $\left(5,311,617\right)$ and they are in arithmetic progression.

Comment: Even a computer based solution or counter example will be fine. My calculations now ran for all numbers below $1.2 \times 10^9$ and there are no solutions for four numbers in AP.

Answer (score 1):

First find three or more primes in arithmetic progression. You can easily show that the first prime is not 2; if the first prime is 3 then there are no more than three numbers in the progression because the fourth number is divisible by 3; if the first prime is >= 5 then the difference between the primes is a multiple of 6, otherwise one of the next two numbers is divisible by 3.

Then count the number of integers $2^{k-1} <= N < 2^k$ where N has three or more distinct prime factors in arithmetic progression, say for k <= 60. You do this by creating a table of primes, finding all primes p, q, r in arithmetic progression with pqr < 2^k from that table (that’s fast, because r = 2q - p, and pqr < 2^k limits the possibilities), then adding pqr to the table, possibly multiplied by p, q, r. And of course the same for more primes in arithmetic progression. But there will be few since their product is limited.

And then you look at your numbers and estimate the chances to find four numbers in arithmetic progression in the table. That chance will be quite small for k = 60. Then you see how these chances change with k, and if the shrink quickly with k, then finding four numbers will be unlikely.

That doesn’t mean it’s impossible, but it might be.

PS. The table of primes you need is not large, the largest r would happen if 3*p*(2p-3) < 2^k, so the largest r is less than sqrt(2^k * 2/3).